# How does one install QGIS from previously downloaded OSGeo packages

Tags: qgis, installation

I have downloaded the OSGeo Installer (on Windows 7 x64) and run it, selecting the Desktop Express Install option.  All of the files were downloaded and the installer reported a successful install, however whilst I could find the downloaded files, I could not find the installed instance.  An OSGeo4W directory was created but contained only a few MB of files.  I have tried to rerun the installer and it only confirmed that the previous installation was successful and that no files needed downloading.  All the downloaded files were still in tarballs so it appears that the installation process after downloading had not taken place.  QGIS has previously been on my system but all previous and development versions were uninstalled using the provided uninstallers.

How to I bring about an installation process that installs desktop QGIS using the files downloaded by the OSGeo Installer?

Comment: Running with admin rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a broken installation. Rename the OSGeo4W directory, and rerun the installation in advanced mode. It should prompt you where to put the installation.

Furthermore, you should have a OSGeo4W folder in your startup menu with shortcuts to the installed programs.

Comment: I deleted the OSGeo4W directory and ran the Desktop Express Installation again.  All the files were downloaded again but the installation succeeded.  Thanks